# Robin's theorem for Mersenne Numbers with Prime Exponent

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The Robin's theorem states $\sigma(n)<e^\gamma n\ln\ln n$ for $n>5041$.

For $n=2^q-1$, $q$ being prime and knowing that the divisors of $2^q-1$ are in the form $2kq+1$, is there a better bound than;

$\sigma(n)<e^\gamma (2^q-1)\ln\ln (2^q-1)$

Thank you in advance.